# Reference for Dual Banach Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Can anyone suggest a good reference book to learn about dual Banach algebras?

I they come up a lot in things I read but I rarely see more than just an on the fly definition, but not much development is supplied as it is not the main topic.

Any good resources that supply a full development of the landscape surrounding them?

Comment: Dear Kyle, Do you mean the dual space to a Banach algebra  (which typically won't again be an algebra, just as the linear dual of an algebra over a field doesn't usually have a natural ring structure), or am I misunderstanding?  Regards,

Comment: I mean Banach algebras which happen to be the dual of a Banach space.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know dual Banach algebras are analogious to von Neumann algebras. Dual Banach algebras are also important in the study of [ameanability of Banach algebras](http://www.math.ku.dk/english/research/ncg/paststudents/RSB_bsthesis.pdf/).

I recommend you the following order of reading in this subject:

- [Dual Banach algebras: An Overview](http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Grundutb/CTH/mve021/1112/conference/slides/runde_handout.pdf)
- [Dual Banach algebras: Connes-amenability, normal, virtual diagonals, and injectivity of the predual bimodule](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305431.pdf)
- [Dual Banach algebras](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~mdaws/talks/dual.pdf)
- [Dual Banach algebras: representations and injectivity](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604372.pdf)
- [A bicommutant theorem for dual Banach algebras](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.1146.pdf)

Of course there are other point of views on dual Banach algebras. This is only one I know.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{General\;Theory\;of\; Banach \;Algebras}\;$ [Book by Charles Earl Rickart] is a good reference for annihilator and dual banach algebra.